# Group officedocuments through mime?

Tags: c, qt, mime-types

I'm working on a backup sollution. The user can assign which folders to backup using a dialog, and a special process is taking care of doing the actual backup, and maintaining versions.

Now, generally the user doesn't want everything to backup, only files which the user has been working on, and possibly various versions exist.

For example: I don't want to backup audio, video and image files. And no archives, but "office" and plain text documents and source files.

It looks like I have to specify every mimetype which can be a lot like:

odt: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
docx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
doc: application/msword

and this only counts for text documents (and there are more, I'm only naming three), I can do something simular for presentations, spreadsheets, etc.

Can I achieve that simple? I mean is there a "functional" definition in mime to determine a file is a text document, a spreadsheet, a presentation, or a source file?

I'm using the mimefunctions from qt. (QMimeType, QMimeDatabase, mimeTypeForFile() etc).

Thanks in advance.

Stef Bon

Comment: Do you know the mimetype for those? Is it the same for say odt, docx, doc, etc? If so, then yes, the aforementioned mime types can achieve your goal.

Comment: @lpapp: I'm  looking for a method to specify groups of mimetypes. I've found a simular question:  442346, but there a big array with all the known mimetypes is suggested. It's a suggestion, but not a good one.